# Tutorial for learning Threat Modeling at enterprise level

Tags: threat-modeling

I am bit new to the field of Information Security. I am aware about OWASP Top 10, SANS Top 25 etc. standards. Recently my job role requires me to learn Threat Modeling. Does any one hold pointer to some good tutorial for learning Threat Modeling and tools used for it at Enterprise level ?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here. So we won't be able to suggest some tools.

Comment: Adam Shostack's book, [Threat Modeling: Designing for Security](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118809998.html) is excellent.

Comment: NIST 800-37 and 163.  Videos by Tony Cox. FAIR course.

Comment: Thanks Xander!  My technical editor, Russ McRee, drove the "IT infrastructure TM guide" https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2009/06/22/it-infrastructure-threat-modeling-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Microsoft Threat Modelling Tool 2016 with study guide.

http://aka.ms/tmt2016

> Microsoft Threat Modeling Tool 2016 is a tool that helps in finding
>   threats in the design phase of software projects. It's available as a
>   free download from the Microsoft Download Center. This latest release
>   simplifies working with threats and provides a new editor for defining
>   your own threats. Microsoft Threat Modeling Tool 2016 has several
>   improvements such as New Threat Grid, Template Editor & Migrating
>   Existing Data Flow Diagrams.